# How to get user records who don't visited in last two months using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables one for saving user session values and second to save user session visit log. I am saving session value when user visit on first time, after that i am only saving visit of that session in visitlog table with date & time. Now i need to get those session record who don't visited in last two months.

**usersessionlog**

```
sessionid
sessionval1
sessionval2
```

**usersessionvisitlog**

```
visitid
sessionid
visitdatetime
```

How can i get those records using mysql query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use NOT EXISTS

```
select t1.sessionid from usersessionlog as t1 where not exists
(select * from usersessionvisitlog as t2 where t1.sessionid =t2.sessionid
 and visitdatetime>=date_add(current_date,interval -2 month))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using left join:

```
select sessionid from usersessionlog sl left join usersessionvisitlog vl 
  on sl.sessionid = vl.sessionid and visitdatetime > now() - interval 2 month
where vl.sessionid is null
```

Usually in MySQL `join` works faster than `in` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
select * from usersessionlog where sessionid not in( select sessionid from where visitdatetime >=DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -2 month))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you used the current date as well then compare it against the visited date you could see which are over 2 months that way.

You may need to look at breaking down the months to see how many days are in each month or you may be able to just see if they are two months apart using the month section